# How to display more fields in an autocomplete reference field in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, entities

In an autocomplete field only the title of the entity reference is displayed to select it.
I would like to display more fields to be more accurate in the selection, but after many research and try different modules I still don't know how to do that :-( 
Can someone help me please?

Comment: you will get title and id in autocomplete field.. Can you please elaborate what type of fields you want?